# How to create login using a POST-request (java to php) in android studio to a webserver with retrofit?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post, retrofit2

In our school project, we're trying to create a login using a POST-request to our webserver in Android Studio, so we can check the username and password in our database etc. We're, however, not very experienced in coding. We have this code to send data to our webserver. There are no problems while debugging, but when clicking on our button, the app crashes. It seems to go wrong in this line: `Call<Response> call = apiInterface.login(username,password);` However, we don't understand what we're doing wrong. This is the code of our MainActivity:

```
package com.example.trafinl;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String username;
    String password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

  
  public void Login(View v){
      username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).toString();
      password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).toString();

      ApiInterface apiInterface;
      apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
      Call<Response> call = apiInterface.login(username,password);


       call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
      if (response.body() != null) {
      //if works --> actions here
      }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
      //if fails --> actions here
      }
      });

       
    }
}
```

This is the code of our XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Gebruikersnaam"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.848" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Wachtwoord"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="Login"
        android:text="@string/loginString"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.047" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skiplogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="skipToHomePage"
        android:text="@string/skipString"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code in ApiClient.java:

```
package com.example.trafinl;


import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String base_URL = "https://etx.com/android/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

        if(retrofit==null){

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

The code in ApiInterface.java:

```
package com.example.trafinl;

import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("https://v63.2021.lodewijk.in/apploginservice.php")
    Call<Response> login(@Field("username") String username,
                         @Field("password") String password);
}
```

(We have yet to start on our php file apploginservice.php)

Is there anyone who can help us with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use .getText() when you saving the entered value:

instead:

```
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).toString();
password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).toString();
```

use:

```
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
```

**EDIT:**
instead of using "Response", use "ResponseBody":

in "ApiInterface":

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;


public interface ApiInterface {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("https://v63.2021.lodewijk.in/apploginservice.php")
Call<ResponseBody> login(@Field("username") String username,
                         @Field("password") String password);
```

}

and change it in your "login" function:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.login(username, password);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {
            //if works --> actions here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        //if fails --> actions here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to do this indeed. However, the app still crashes when we click the button..

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer - you needed to change your call to expect result of: "ResponeBody"
(:

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't crash anymore now